# Install nginx module on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to use the [ngx_http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) on my elastic beanstalk instances however it does not come standard with `nginx` so it must enabled with the `--with-http_realip_module` configuration parameter, however I can't seem to find any AWS documentation that instructs you how to do this.

How can I force elastic beanstalk to install `nginx` with `realip` enabled?

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, you can install NGINX modules (or any other software) on EB instances using [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). The appropriate hook for installing software seems to be `predeploy`.

While there doesn't seem to be realip module in the repositories, here's how you'd add the http-geoip module. Create a file `.platform/hooks/predeploy/01_install_mod_geoip.sh` and `chmod +x` it. In it, add:

```
#!/bin/sh

yum install nginx-mod-http-geoip
```

Comment: This answer describes how to build an nginx dynamic module that is not available in yum: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76957722/953887

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not already configured with it? When I run `nginx -V` on my EB instance I do see that module included:

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.8.0
built by gcc 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-google_perftools_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt=' -Wl,-E'
```

If you scroll right you'll see that `--with-http_realip_module` was configured.

I have not tested the module in any way. I'm just pointing out that the flag was set.