# Install a dynamic nginx module on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, http-headers, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to remove the "Server" HTTP header, added by nginx. The module [headers-more-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) adds this functionality.

This module is not available in the default Amazon `yum` repository.

How can I add the module to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances running on Amazon Linux 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to compile the module from source code, as a "dynamic module". Here is an example, specifically for `headers-more-nginx-module`.

Assuming you upload your application to Elastic Beanstalk in a zip file, the zip should contain three files, with contents as below.

### `.ebextensions/01-nginx-modules.config`

```yaml
# Install any system-level dependencies required to build nginx or your module
packages:
  yum:
    pcre2-devel: []
    zlib-devel: []

# Download the source for your nginx module
sources:
  /root: https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module/archive/refs/tags/v0.34.tar.gz
```

#### `.platform/hooks/predeploy/01-nginx-modules.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit -o pipefail -o verbose

# Ensure we start in the user home dir
cd ~

# Dynamically get the current version of nginx
nginx -V &> nginx_version.txt
nginx_version=$(grep -oP "(?<=nginx version: nginx/).*" ./nginx_version.txt)

# Download and extract nginx
wget -O nginx.tar.gz http://nginx.org/download/nginx-"${nginx_version}".tar.gz
tar -xzvf nginx.tar.gz

# Build the module. Most of the settings are copied from `nginx -V`, in case they're required for binary compatibility.
# We really just add `--add-dynamic-module` to the end.
cd nginx-"${nginx_version}"/
./configure \
  --prefix=/usr/share/nginx \
  --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
  --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules \
  --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
  --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
  --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body \
  --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy \
  --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi \
  --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi \
  --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi \
  --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid \
  --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx \
  --user=nginx \
  --group=nginx \
  --with-compat \
  --with-debug \
  --with-file-aio \
  --with-mail=dynamic \
  --with-pcre \
  --with-pcre-jit \
  --with-stream=dynamic \
  --with-threads \
  --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic' \
  --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-E' \
  --add-dynamic-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.34/
make modules

# Copy the module somewhere it can be loaded dynamically.
# Overwrite any existing file (`\cp`, to skip the alias for `cp -i`, which prompts for overwrite).
\cp objs/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so /usr/share/nginx/modules/

# Edit the staged default nginx.conf, just inserting the `load_module` directive.
# (This can't live in a `conf.d/` file, which only allows extending the `http` directive.)
# The `sed` comment will insert (/i) our code before the line containing `events {`.
# `-i.bak` will update the file in place, saving the original version as a new file with extension `.bak`.
sed -i.bak \
  '/events {/i # Hide the Server HTTP header\nload_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;\n' \
  /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
```

### `.platform/nginx/conf.d/01-remove-headers.conf`

```
more_clear_headers Server;
```

This is is where you apply any directives within the `http` context.

## Risks

1. Downloading from github.com and nginx.com means your app deployment could fail if either host is unavailable, or if the files move on those third-party servers.
2. Installing dependencies, downloading source code, and compiling the module on each deployment will slow down your app deployments.
3. Updates to Amazon Linux 2 (or changing the OS) could change the version of nginx, or the compilation flags, which create binary incompatibility.

These risks could be mitigated by:

1. Storing the source packages on S3.
2. Storing the compiled module in S3, and make the compilation a manual step. (Devs could compile nginx in a VM.)
3. ... hmm...